# can anyone have idea that how to create edit action for ui component based custom grid in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, custom-grid

```
app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/adminhtml/ui_component/mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.xml
```

Here below I want to add edit button column as Action column. Actually I want to fetch each  record using id.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<columns name="spinner_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="post_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code in your `mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.xml` file

```
<columns>
...
...
<actionsColumn class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions" name="actions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</actionsColumn>
...
...
</columns>
```

Create `Actions.php` file

> app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Actions.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class BlogActions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'your_route/your_controller/your_edit_action';
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'your_route/your_controller/your_delete_action';
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['post_id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                                [
                                    'post_id' => $item['post_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit')
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                                [
                                    'post_id' => $item['post_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                            'confirm' => [
                                'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.title }"'),
                                'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a "${ $.$data.title }" record?')
                            ]
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me please how to load controller for  edit action in custom grid,actually i am not able to fetch record using id in custom grid

Comment: See the above code. There is an edit action with  `post_id`. You can get this `post_id` in your controller using `$this->getRequest()->getParam('post_id');`

Comment: Yes its working fine.. but edit grid not displaying because i dont find any code for ui component edit grid i know layout edit grid...

Comment: Follow these articles 

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-grid-using-ui-component/

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html